# Nativescript list-view with multiple item templates toggling visibility

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, radlistview

I have an issue with the radlistview with multiple item templates and toggling visibility. 
I'm trying to re-create an according type display without using the nativescript-accordion plugin. By toggling the visibility attribute for a given item. Here's my xml:

```
<lv:RadListView row="3" items="{{ locationList }}" id="locationList" iosEstimatedRowHeight="0" itemTap="listViewItemTap" itemTemplateSelector="templateSelector" class="list-group">
        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplates>
            <template key="header">
                <GridLayout columns="auto, *" visibility="{{ isItemVisible ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
...content...</GridLayout>
</template>
            <template key="list-item">
                <GridLayout columns="*, auto" rows="auto, 15" visibility="{{ isItemVisible ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">...content...
</GridLayout>
</template>
</lv:RadListView.itemTemplates>
</lv:RadListView>
```

Here's the itemTap method:

```
if (tappedItem.type == "list-item" || tappedItem.type == "list-item-no-location") {
        // Navigate to the details page with context set to the data item for specified index
        topmost().navigate({....}});
    } else if (tappedItem.type == "header") {
        viewModel.collapseExpandItems(tappedItem);

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (platformModule.isIOS) {
            // Uncomment the lines below to avoid default animation
            // UIView.animateWithDurationAnimations(0, () => {
                var indexPaths = NSMutableArray.new();
                indexPaths.addObject(NSIndexPath.indexPathForRowInSection(rowIndex, args.groupIndex));
                //console.log("indexPaths:", indexPaths);
                listView.ios.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths);
            // });
            }
            if (platformModule.isAndroid) {
                listView.androidListView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(rowIndex);
            }
        }, 550);
```

And for the loading of the items, here is some code:

```
var newHeader = new Item(location.type, location.id, location.name, ..., true);
viewModel.locationList.push(newHeader);
var newItem = new Item(listItem.type, listItem.id, listItem.name, ... , true);
viewModel.locationList.push(newItem);
```

`locationList` being the ObservableArray in the viewModel.
And here is the Item class in the viewModel:

```
var Item = (function (_super) {
        __extends(Item, _super);
        function Item(type, id, name, ..., isItemVisible) {
            var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
            _this.type = type;
...
            _this.isItemVisible = isItemVisible;
            return _this;
        }
        Item.prototype.toggleVisibility = function (args) {
            // console.dir(this);
            console.log("toggleVisibility value: " + this.isItemVisible);
            this.set("isItemVisible", !this.isItemVisible);
        };
        return Item;
    }(Observable.Observable));
```

And finally the viewModel.collapseExpandItems method in the viewModel:

```
collapseExpandItems: function(tappedItem) {
            this.locationList.forEach(function(item) {
                //console.log("isItemVisible:", item.isItemVisible);
                if ((item.type === 'list-item') && item.id === tappedItem.id) {
                    item.toggleVisibility();
                }
            });
        },
```

It's hiding the items below the header item, but all the items below, even the ones that were not set to visibilty="collapsed".
Please see .gif for the behavior. Any ideas?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJCGA.gif)

It seems like momentarily its doing the right thing, but then it hides everything under, which is not what I want. I want it to just hide the items under the tapped header.

Comment: Hi @GShep, Try using RadListView's `refresh` method - https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html#refresh instead of `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths ` and check if you still are facing the same issue.

Comment: The problem with refresh method is that it would reload the list view and won't retain the scroll position and all. @GShep can you create a playground example which may be easier to debug?

Comment: @NikolayTsonev i've also tried using the `refresh` method of `listview`, same result in terms of behavior.  @Manoj  i'll try to create a playground later on today...

Comment: Indeed it will help if you can provide an example, which can be used for recreating the issue.

Comment: Hi! Finally able to get that playground example working: (https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=eC5qGO&v=34). Please note, the code works as desired on Android, no problem. Seems to be only on iOS. Maybe something to do with the order of events fired that are different on iOS from Android...